# Which is more stable chemically: DNA or peptide

Tags: stability, proteins, dna-rna

Assuming enzyme-free environment, and the DNA and peptide are lyophillized, and then stored in vials under the same conditions (temperature and humidity).

On average, which would be more chemically stable,

- in terms of backbone cleavage?
- in terms of loss of side chain?

Comment: You know what holds each of them together, don’t you?

Comment: Yes, so is it correct that the answer boils down to the relative size of Gibbs Free Energy of the hydrolysis of Phosphodiester bond and Peptide bond? If it is true, where can I find these information? It seems that there's not much information on solid state stability.

Comment: Why solid state?

Comment: Because the samples are freeze-dried and stored in low humidity, so I can assume the samples to be in solid state.

Comment: I would consider the liquid state, though, since they won’t be cleaved in the absence of water.

Comment: Proteins are more stable, but this is only tre for collagen type 1 specifically. Not all proteins.

Answer (score 1):

Well, more than 1 year has passed, and now the field of palaeo-proteomics is born, I think the verdict is clear:

The winner is PEPTIDE.
Still found intact in tens of millions old extinct animals, where DNA had degraded for long.

Source: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature14249